# List subdirectories only instead of full directory

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am using an internal command of Windows command interpreter to get all the files in the current directory and sub-directories:

```
dir /s /b /o:gn > output.txt
```

It gives me an output like:

```
C:\ParentDir\CurrentDir\ChilderDir\AnApp.exe
```

I want instead the output:

```
ChilderDir\AnApp.exe
```

How to get the files and directories list without current directory path?

Comment: It's an exmaple haha, a joke :) thought you guys would appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This batch code could be used to get the directory and file name list without base path.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

rem The environment variable CD holds path of current directory without a
rem backslash at end, except the current directory is the root directory
rem of a drive. This must be taken into account to get current directory
rem path with a backslash at end.

if "%CD:~-1%" == "\" (
    set "CurrentDirectory=%CD%"
) else (
    set "CurrentDirectory=%CD%\"
)

rem Delete the output file in current directory if already existing.
if exist output.txt del /F output.txt

rem Get recursive the directory and file names not having system or hidden
rem attribute set and remove from each directory and file name the current
rem directory path. With DIR parameter /A directories and files with hidden
rem or system attribute would be also included in the list. The output file
rem output.txt is also in the list.

for /F "delims=" %%I in ('dir /B /S /O:GN 2^>nul') do (
    set "FileNameWithFullPath=%%I"
    echo !FileNameWithFullPath:%CurrentDirectory%=!>>output.txt
)

endlocal
```

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `if /?`
- `rem /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

The error message output by command **DIR** to handle *STDERR* on no none hidden/system directory or file in current directory found is redirected to device **NUL** to suppress it using `2>nul` whereby redirection operator `>` must be escaped here with `^` to be applied on execution of **DIR** instead of being interpreted as redirection for command **FOR** at an invalid position in command line which would result in a syntax error message on execution. See also the Microsoft article [Using command redirection operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx).